# Link text changes on click. See more, See less jquery - Bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've used `bootstrap` accordion to hide/unhide info.

I needed the wording to change from 'See more' to 'See less' continuously.

I've implemented this as you can see in the [bootply](http://bootply.com/106255)

As you will see, the problem I'm facing is that when first clicked it moves from 'See more' to 'See more' then click again it starts working as I want it to.

I know why its happening but cant figure out how I can remove the a href text and show the hidden info straight away.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#morebtn").click(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html() == "See more" ? "See less" : "See more");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because first time round your HTML is actually `<strong>See more</strong>` not "See more" as you think.
Change it to `$(this).text() == "See more"` and it works :)
You can then just add a class to the element to make it bold. Otherwise you'll need to re-wrap with the `<strong>` tag each time

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(this).html($(this).text() == "See more" ? "See less" : "See more");
```

Or if #morebtn is `<a> tag` do like this:

```
$(this).text(function(index,text){
   return text ? "See less" : "See more"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the  tag around your See more text and apply that style via css, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 $(this).html(($(this).html() == "See more" )? "See less" : "See more");
```

tested worked for me

ensure that id is given to dom element which support html() property

i tried with

```
  <div id="morebtn"  style="background-color:red;width:64px;height:56px;"></div>
```

if id given to button then use

```
    $(this).attr('value',($(this).attr('value') == "See more" )? "See less" : "See more");
```