# HTML markup inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a icon next to some link text that makes an accordion expand and collapse. The text already changes from 'See more' to 'See less'. see the working demo - http://bootply.com/106271

So adding:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
```

stops the text change work.

Here is the broken version trying to add the icon: http://bootply.com/106270

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#morebtn").click(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html() == "See more <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>" ? "See less" : "See more <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>");
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).html('.....')`

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159802/link-text-changes-on-click-see-more-see-less-jquery-bootstrap-accordion/21159947#21159947

Comment: Don't replace the whole html...there are better ways to traverse the DOM. You should just be replacing the text, and changing the classes for the nested span

Comment: @TomRudge You have asked same question twice!

Comment: Its a different question, just so happens its about the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mismatching quotes:

```
"See more <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" ... "
^                     ^                              ^     ^
```

To fix this, either use single quotes or escape the double quotes:

```
'See more <span class=" ... " ... '

"See more <span class=\" ... \" ... "
```

[**Working Bootply Demo**](http://bootply.com/106272).

Answer (score 2):

Use `.indexOf()` to check the availability of a particular word. And also keep in mind that dont use `"` inside of a string which is being constructed by `"` instead use `'`

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#morebtn").click(function(){
       $(this).html($(this).html().indexOf("See more") > -1 ? "See less" : "See more <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span>");
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the whole web site html content with

```
$(this).hmtl("");
```

Isn´t a good idea.

Instead of using that, you doing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                    $("#morebtn").click(function()
                                        {
                                            $("#morebtn").val($("#morebtn").val().indexOf("See more") === 1 ?
                                                              $("#morebtn").val("See less")
                                                              : $("#morebtn").val('See more <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>'));
                                        }
                                );
                  }
            );
```

It is also worth to mention, that this line could not work:

```
"See more <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"
```

Your JavaScript console should show up a syntax error for this. Because you can´t use implicit the same quotes withou escaping the inner ones. You have to escape your inner double quotes like this:

```
class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up\"
```

OR: I highly recommend you to use the alternative method with single and double quotes (the order doesn´t matter), because it´s easier readable for human beings. It could be single or double first):

```
'See more <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>'
// or:
"See more <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span>"
```

Hopefully this has helped you.